# Connecting Microsoft Copilot to Salesforce Einstein Handoff

Tags: salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-einstein, microsoft-copilot

I am looking into integrating Microsoft copilot with Salesforce Einstein.  In the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-copilot-studio/customer-copilot-salesforce-handoff) it has the below.  I imagine individuals will probably be googling this like crazy eventually with the rising popularity of Microsoft Copilot.

How best would it be to perform the below?

Step 3: Create Apex Classes to connect to DirectLine API

Log in to your Salesforce account.
In Salesforce, navigate to Setup.
In the Quick Find box, type Apex Classes.
Create three new classes with the following details:
DL_GetConversation

Inputs: None
Outputs: (String) conversationId, (Integer) responseCode, (String) errorMessage
InvocableMethod getConversationID, use your DirectLine Secret to make an HTTP call to the DirectLine endpoint starting a conversation
DL_PostActivity

Inputs: (String) conversationId, (String) userMessage
Outputs: (Integer) responseCode, (String) errorMessage, (String) watermark
InvocableMethod postActivity: Execute an HTTP call to the post activity DirectLine API using the conversationId in the URL and userMessage
DL_GetActivity

Inputs: (String) conversationId, (String) watermark
Outputs: (String) message, (String) watermark, (Integer) responseCode, (String) errorMessage
InvocableMethod getActivity: Execute an HTTP call to the get activity DirectLine API, using the conversationId and watermark to retrieve and parse the activity object for the message to send back to the user

I have tried googling, unfortunately, to no avail, and no one has done a sample code regarding this.  It is probably because of how young Microsoft Copilot is.